# Mixing Scoped proxy and @configurable Annotation in Spring

Tags: spring, hibernate, aspectj

I am trying to do this:
I have created an abstract factory which provides me concrete factories.I use concrete factory  to create object.The object is basically created by new keyword in the concrete factory.
Now this newly created object needs to autowire beans and the scope of these beans are request or session so i used scoped proxy around them.

I learned that it is possible using ASPECT J to do autowiring to objects created with new keyword.So I tried to configure it.
I am using my eclipse and in built tomcat 6  and NO build tool.

1.scoped proxy beans were configured using cglib and working perfectly.
2.then i created factories to create concrete objects.
3.problem arise when i use @configurable annotation.

Here is my step by step code.

THIS IS THE CONCRETE FACTORY

public class LoadEntityFactory extends EntitiesAbstractFactory {

```
@Override
public loadEntities getLoadEntity(String entity) {
    if(entity==null){
        return null;
    }else if (entity.equalsIgnoreCase("categories")) {

        return new LoadCategoryEntity();
    }
    else if (entity.equalsIgnoreCase("books")) {
        return new LoadBookEntity();
    }

    return null;
}
```

}

THIS IS MY CLASS WHICH IS CREATED BY CONCRETE FACTORY AND WHICH NEEDS TO AUTOWIRE SOME OTHER SCOPED PROXY BEANS(which in my case is a service)

```
@Configurable
public class LoadCategoryEntity implements loadEntities {

    private InputStream iStream;
    private category_pojo categories;

    private Set<category_pojo> categorySet;

    public EntitiesLoadService categoryLoadService;





    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("categoryLoadService")
    public void setCategoryLoadService(EntitiesLoadService categoryLoadService) {
        this.categoryLoadService = categoryLoadService;
    }
```

here is my code of the class whose object needs to be autowired in LoadCategoryEntity

```
@Service("categoryLoadService")
@Transactional
@Scope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS,value="request")
public class CategoryEntityLoadService implements EntitiesLoadService {


    private AbstractHibernateDAO categDAO;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("categDAO")
    public void setCategDAO(AbstractHibernateDAO categDAO) {
        this.categDAO = categDAO;
    }
```

here is my DAO

```
@Repository("categDAO")
@Scope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS,value="request")
public class CategoryDAO extends AbstractHibernateDAO<category_pojo>{

}
```

I HAVE PROVIDED JAVAAGENT PARAMETER TO VM
-javaagent:C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\UserLibrary\spring-agent-2.5.6.jar

AND I HAVE BELOW ANNOTATION IN APPLICATION CONTEXT

```
<context:load-time-weaver />
```

I AM GETTING LONG LIST OF ERRORS ,SO I AM PASTING WHAT SEEMS APPROPRIATE

stack trace

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect.invokeWithinTransaction(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Class;Lorg/springframework/transaction/interceptor/TransactionAspectSupport$InvocationCallback;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect.ajc$around$org_springframework_transaction_aspectj_AbstractTransactionAspect$1$2a73e96c(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:63)
    at com.ClickToShop.Service.UserServiceImpl.setUserDAO(UserServiceImpl.java:40)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:594)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
    ... 39 more
Aug 21, 2013 10:34:57 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet MyDispatcherServlet
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect.invokeWithinTransaction(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Class;Lorg/springframework/transaction/interceptor/TransactionAspectSupport$InvocationCallback;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect.ajc$around$org_springframework_transaction_aspectj_AbstractTransactionAspect$1$2a73e96c(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:63)
    at com.ClickToShop.Service.UserServiceImpl.setUserDAO(UserServiceImpl.java:40)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:594)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:314)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:910)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:853)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:768)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:558)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:871)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:423)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:443)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:459)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:340)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:307)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1161)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:806)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:129)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:261)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:581)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

also many messages like this

```
when weaving classes 
when weaving 
 [Xlint:cantFindType]
[WebappClassLoader@1bcdbf6] error can't determine annotations of missing type org.springframework.cache.annotation.CachePut
when weaving type org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$HashCodeInterceptor
when weaving classes 
when weaving 
 [Xlint:cantFindType]
[WebappClassLoader@1bcdbf6] error can't determine annotations of missing type org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable
when weaving type org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$HashCodeInterceptor
when weaving classes 
when weaving 
 [Xlint:cantFindType]
[WebappClassLoader@1bcdbf6] error can't determine annotations of missing type org.springframework.cache.annotation.CacheEvict
when weaving type org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$ProxyCallbackFilter
when weaving classes 
when weaving 
 [Xlint:cantFindType]
```

Comment: Can you post your classpath? Judging from the stacktrace you are either missing required jar, mixing spring versions or have the same jar in different places (leading to be loaded by different classloaders).

Comment: I resolved the problem .don't remember exactly what the issue was.but it was something related to missing or mixed jars.please have a look at my other question.stil struggling to use mvc:resources.Also suggest me some tutorials to learn maven with my eclipse.